# How to resolve "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" in java socket

Tags: java, sockets, exception, connection

I write a socket server demo, socket server code:
when i run server, it's ok.
so i run client to connect it 
my server code:

```
public class BIOSocketServer {
//TLV
/**
 * data frame size: 100
 * 1st Byte: data type,
 * 2nd Byte: date length
 * 3~100: data content
 */
private byte[] messageFrame = new byte[100];
private boolean isEnd;
private String data;

public void startServer(ServerConfig config) throws Exception {
    int serverPort = config.getPort();
    int maxConnections = config.getMaxConnection();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort, maxConnections);
    try {
        for (; ; ) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    // read data
                    InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                    int byteRead = 0;
                    messageFrame[0] = dataInputStream.readByte();
                    messageFrame[1] = dataInputStream.readByte();
                    byteRead = messageFrame[1];
                    while (!isEnd) {
                        byteRead = dataInputStream.read(messageFrame);
                        data += new String(messageFrame, 0, byteRead);
                        if (data.length() == byteRead) {
                            isEnd = true;
                        }
                    }
                    LOG.info("Message: {}", data);

                    // write
                    messageFrame = new byte[100];
                    messageFrame[0] = 0x01;
                    String message = "Hello";
                    System.arraycopy(message, 0, messageFrame, 2, message.length());
                    int length = messageFrame.length;
                    System.arraycopy(length, 0, messageFrame, 1, 8);
                    outputStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    //...close
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

the server accept frame, size is 100, and the first byte store data type, and sencond byte store data length, and othre byte store content.
my test code is :

```
and my test code is, when i run it, read data from client, and exception "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

@Test
public void testSendMessageToServer() {
    try {
        client = new Socket("localhost", 8089);
        byte [] messageFrame = new byte[100];
        messageFrame[0] = 0x01; //type
        messageFrame[1] = 0x64; //length
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.write(messageFrame);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

how to resolve the problem?

Comment: 'Connection reset' can be caused by the peer closing without reading everything you sent. `byteRead = dataInputStream.read(messageFrame)`: use `readFully()` here if you already know the length, and get rid of the loop. You should also look into `read/writeUTF()` for the strings.